# Youtube API Get each playlist and its containing videos from channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

**I'm trying to create a list of Youtube playlists and each list item to contain the playlist's videos as well.**

Something like this (this would be a playlist section):

[image: Playlist Section]

The issue I'm having is when calling the `requestVideoPlaylist` function inside the `renderPlaylistSection` I get `undefined`. However, if I call the `requestVideoPlaylist` with a given `playlistId` outside of the `render...` function the result gets returned correctly.

Please find my code on the following lines.

I've also made a reproduction on [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pxp8hgoy/)

```
// Retrieve the list of playlists
function requestPlaylists(channelId) {
  playlistsContainer.html('');
  var requestOptions = {
    channelId: channelId,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails',
    maxResults: 4
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list(requestOptions);
  request.execute(function(response) {
    var playlists = response.result.items;
    if (playlists) {
      $.each(playlists, function(index, item) {
        renderPlaylistSection(playlistsContainer, item.id, item.snippet);
      });
    } else {
      playlistsContainer.html('Sorry, you have no uploaded videos');
    }
  });
}

// Retrieve the list of videos in the specified playlist.
function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, pageToken) {
  var requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails',
    maxResults: 5
  };
  if (pageToken) {
    requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
  request.execute(function(response) {
    // Only show pagination buttons if there is a pagination token for the
    // next or previous page of results.
    nextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
    var nextVis = nextPageToken ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    $('.js-next-videos').css('visibility', nextVis);
    prevPageToken = response.result.prevPageToken
    var prevVis = prevPageToken ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    $('.js-prev-videos').css('visibility', prevVis);

    var playlistItems = response.result.items;
    if (playlistItems) {
      $.each(playlistItems, function(index, item) {
        if (this.snippet.thumbnails) {
          renderVideoItem(item.snippet);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// Render playlist section
function renderPlaylistSection(container, playlistId, playlistSnippet) {
  var title = playlistSnippet.title;

  container.append(
    '<div class="playlist"><h3>Playlist Title: ' + title + '</h3>' +
    '<div class="row playlist-videos">' + requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId) + '</div></div>'
  );
}

function renderVideoItem(videoSnippet) {
  var title = videoSnippet.title;
  var thumbnail = videoSnippet.thumbnails.medium.url;

  return (
    '<div class="thumb" style="overflow: hidden;">' +
    '<img src="' + thumbnail + '">' +
    '</div>'
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems to me like `requestVideoPlaylist()` does not return anything, as there is no `return` statement being accessed. This would be the reason for the "undefined" website content: You're trying to put the return value of the method in the page (when calling `renderPlaylistSection()`), as there is none, the result is "undefined".

Comment: You could say the result of `renderVideoItem(item.snippet);` in line 61 is being ignored. To add the result of this to the page it seems as you have to reorder your code a little.